# How to pivot data group by condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, pivot

I have a data as follow (all in a table PRODUCT_STATUS)

```
CatID   ProductID    Active
C01    P001         True
C01    P002         False
C01    P003         True
C02    P001         False
C01    P004         False
```

Now, I want pivot as follow , In here : with parameter C01, select group by C01.

```
CatID       P001         P002        P003          P004
C01        1             0            1            0
```

I use

```
create PROC GET_GROUP_STATUS @GID CHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ColumnHeaders = STUFF( (SELECT ', [' + ProductID + ']' 
                         FROM PRODUCT_STATUS
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
                        , 1, 2, '');
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 
'SELECT * FROM
 (
     SELECT CatID, ProductID , CAST(ALLOW AS INT) AS ALLOW
     FROM PRODUCT_STATUS
     WHERE CatID = @GID
 ) t
 PIVOT
 (
     MAX([ALLOW]) FOR [ALLOW] IN (' + @ColumnHeaders + ')
 ) p';
--PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@GID CHAR(3)', @GID
END
```

I run store GET_GROUP_STATUS C01 , but seem it's not working.

Comment: what is your result after run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to run this, but first tips:

1. Do not paste some code, say it don't work, and wait that someone repair it.
2. If you do as in 1), prepare environment to reproduce error using for example [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), it will be much easier to help.
3. Put some effort to describe what you want to achieve, not only data => result
4. Answer the comments.
5. Describe errors you get.

Here is the answer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_GROUP_STATUS] 
                 @GID CHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @ColumnHeaders = STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ', [' + ProductID + ']' 
                     FROM PRODUCT_STATUS
                     /*WHERE CatId = @GID */
                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
                    , 1, 2, '');            

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT CatId, ' + @ColumnHeaders + ' FROM
 (
 SELECT CatID, ProductId, [Active] = (CASE WHEN Active = ''True'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 FROM [dbo].[PRODUCT_STATUS]
 WHERE CatID = @GID
 ) t
 PIVOT
 (
     MAX([Active]) FOR [ProductId] IN (' + @ColumnHeaders + ')
 ) p';

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] @SQL, N'@GID CHAR(3)', @GID;
END
```

Usage:

`EXECUTE  [dbo].[GET_GROUP_STATUS] @GID = 'C01'`  -- answer as you 
 posted

`EXECUTE  [dbo].[GET_GROUP_STATUS] @GID = 'C02'`  -- for this you will get (null) for products [P002-P004]

For anyone who wants to [play with it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91846/42).